# Symbolic Series Expansion collecting specific term

Tags: series-expansion

Is there a way to automatically Collect[] the ω terms by their powers for this expression?

```
expression=Sum[I*E^(I*m*t*ω)*m*ω*p[1, m, t] + E^(I*m*t*ω)*Derivative[0, 0, 1][p][1, m, t], {m, 1, mlimit}]/ω;
Collect[ExpandAll[expression], ω]
```

This just returns `expression` -- it fails to separate terms within the summations.  What I really want is this:

```
Sum[I*E^(I*m*t*ω)*m*p[1, m, t], {m, 1, mlimit}] + Sum[E^(I*m*t*ω)*Derivative[0, 0, 1][p][1, m, t], {m, 1, mlimit}]/ω
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably have to pull out the factor of ω yourself.  You can automate this with something like:

```
ClearAll[myCollect]
myCollect[a_. + b_.*sum : Sum[c_.*Power[var_, n_.] + d_., argsSum__], 
  vars : var_ | {___, var_, ___}, argsCollect___] := 
    myCollect[a + b*(Power[var, n] Sum[c, argsSum] + Sum[d, argsSum]), 
      vars, argsCollect]

myCollect[args___] := Collect[args]
```

Then you can do

```
myCollect[ExpandAll[expression], ω]
```

> $\frac{\sum _{m=1}^{\text{mlimit}} e^{i m t \omega } p^{(0,0,1)}(1,m,t)}{\omega }+\sum _{m=1}^{\text{mlimit}} i m e^{i m t \omega } p(1,m,t)$

---

Of course this implementation has some limitations.  Most notably:

- It is assumed that `Power[var,n]` is otherwise independent of the sum's iterator.  This would fail, for example, for $\sum_m \omega^m $
- Powers of $\omega$ are only found at level 2 in the sum.  For example, the $\omega$ in $\sum_m(a + b (\omega + c))$ would not be picked up.

Comment: Excellent, thanks